# doctrine2 get a list of entities not having a collection

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

This is my problem : I have a user entity with a oneToMany relationship on Address entity.
I want in a single query get all my users with no address. This is my querybuilder :

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
    ->where('u.enabled = :enabled')
    ->setParameter('enabled', true)
    //->andWhere('u.addresses ..... ?? how to do that ?
    ->orderBy('u.created', 'DESC');

    if ( is_int($limit) && $limit > 0 ) {
        $qb = $qb->setFirstResult($offset)
                 ->setMaxResults($limit);
    }

    return $qb;
```

I don't know how, in one query, retrieve all users with NO address only...
Can someone help me please ?

Answer (score 2):

From [DQL Documentation examples](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-select-examples), using `IS EMPTY`

```php
$qb = $this
    ->createQueryBuilder('u')
    ->where('u.enabled = :enabled')
    ->setParameter('enabled', true)
    ->andWhere('u.addresses IS EMPTY')
    ->orderBy('u.created', 'DESC');

    if ($limit) {
        $qb = $qb
            ->setFirstResult($offset)
            ->setMaxResults($limit);
    }

    return $qb;
```

Comment: That's what i tried, but instead of "IS EMPTY" i put "IS NULL", and it works

Comment: @emurb you would put `IS NULL` for single-valued associations and state fields